# How to use @value annotation in kotlin data class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have an application.properties file like:

```
person-one-name=John
```

This is my data class, I have used @Value annotation outside dataclass.

```
@Value("\${person-one-name}")
lateinit var personOne: String

data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) {
        constructor(age: Int) : this(personOne, age)
}
```

I want to use the var personOne in my data class.

It gives an error lateinit property personOne has not been initialized

Comment: For `@Value` to be processed this needs to be in a class that is annotated with a Spring annotation like `@Component`.  I don't think you'll get this to work successfully.  I think you should keep data classes to not have any of this automation, but create the `Person` object from a Service/Factory class that is configured by Spring.

Comment: Can you give any simple example of a service/factory class that is configured by spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from my comment under the Question:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

@Service
class PersonFactory(
    @Value("\${person-one-name}")
    private val personOne: String,
) {

    fun createPerson(name: String? = null, age: Int) =
        if (name != null) Person(name, age)
        else Person(personOne, age)
}
```

Another gotcha, is that the `PersonFactory` service needs to be in a package at the same level or within the class that starts the App.

More info: https://springhow.com/a-guide-to-value-in-spring-boot/